# Is the chromatic number of the graph of the permutahedron known?

Tags: graph-theory, convex-polytopes, graph-colorings, permutations

The permutahedron $\Pi_n$ is the polytope that is the convex hull of all permutations of the vector $(1,2,...,n)$. There are many results on its structure, but I couldn't find a result on the chromatic number of its 1-skeleton. Is it known?

Comment: It is bipartite; color a permutation with its sign.